# Two counts in just one SOLR query

Tags: solr, solrj

My question is: How could I realize two counts in just one SOLR query? I have tried something like this:

```
q=query&field:[* TO *],-field:[* TO *]&start=0&rows=0&facet=true&facet.missing=true
```

i.e. I am trying to count null records and not null records for the same field.

No error reported but no result retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you both counts:

```
q=query&facet=true&facet.query=field:[* TO *]&facet.query=-field:[* TO *]&rows=0
```